# DOMContentLoaded with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

i was wondering why I can't add an Event Listener inside my DOMContentLoaded function, my problem is that he fires the click before it loads and then doesnt do anything after:

HTML

```
<body>
This is a test.<br>
</body>
```

JS
    //DOMContentLoaded...

```
var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t=document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
btn.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(btn);

btn.addEventListener('click',alert('HELLO!'),false);
```

I made a fiddle of this:
http://jsfiddle.net/hH5Lh/

I have to use DOMContentLoaded because on my code I have XMLHTTP requests that can only be triggered after my html has been loaded...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you need to assign a *function* as the event callback.  `alert('HELLO!')` will *call* the `alert` function and pass its return value (`undefined`) as the event callback.

You want to do this:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('HELLO!');
}, false);
```

Comment: @JoshHarrison: I'm a ninja ^~^